# Full rank of $[A^0 v | A^1 v | A^2 v | \ldots | A^{d-1} v]$ when A is non-diagonalizeable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm considering a $d \times d$ square matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and a given vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and I'm wondering when the matrix $$\Sigma = [A^0v \quad A^1 v \quad A^2v\quad\ldots\quad A^{d-1}v]$$
has full rank (with $A^0$ being the identity matrix $I_d$).

The vector $v$ is considered given, so (I think) this is not just a question of whether a such $v$ exists, which I've seen discussed a few places. (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025304/prove-that-t-has-a-cyclic-vector-iff-its-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomial)).

As [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2793456/688735) explains, *if $A$ is diagonalizable*, this is equivalent to **$A$ having $d$ distinct eigenvalues and that $v$ cannot be written as a linear combination of $m < d$ of the eigenvalues of $A$**.

But in the case that $A$ is not diagonalizable, I cannot come up with a similar criterion. Inspired by the diagonalizable case, one could think that again distinct eigenvalues would be the key. But if
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad v = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},
$$
$A$ has eigenvalues $1, 1$ and $2$, but
$[v \quad Av\quad A^2v] = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ has full rank still.

(Observe that if one removes the off-diagonal in $A$, it becomes diagonalizable and so by the non-unique eigenvalues, it doesn't have full rank).

Can anyone phrase conditions on $A$ and $v$ to determine whether the cyclic subspace has full rank?

Comment: [Here is a list](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1787808/81360) of conditions on $A$, each of which is equivalent to the existence of such a vector $v$ (which is called a cyclic vector).

Comment: I suspect that whenever $A$ admits a cyclic vector, it will hold that "most" vectors are cyclic (i.e. the set of cyclic vectors is Zariski dense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$A$ admits a cyclic vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1787808/81360) if and only if its Jordan form consists of only one Jordan block for each of its distinct eigenvalues.

Given that $A$ admits a cyclic vector, let $J$ denote the Jordan form of $A$, and $S$ be a similarity transformation for which $S^{-1}AS = J$.  Suppose that
$$
J = J_{m_1}(\lambda_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus J_{m_k}(\lambda_k),
$$
where $J_m(\lambda)$ denotes the size-$m$ Jordan block associated with $\lambda$, and $\oplus$ denotes a [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum).

> **Claim:** Given that $A$ satisfies the above, we can state the following:
>
> - $v$ is a cyclic vector of $J$ if and only if the $j$th component of $v$ is non-zero for each $j$ of the form $j = \sum_{p=1}^q m_p$ for $q=1,\dots,k$. In other words, $v$ is cyclic iff the components corresponding to the final column of each Jordan block are non-zero.
> - $w$ is a cyclic vector of $A$ if and only if $S^{-1}w$ is a cyclic vector of $J$.

It is easy to show that the first statement implies the second, but proving the first is perhaps a bit trickier.  In this statement, the difficult direction of proof is showing that every such $v$ is indeed cyclic. One proof strategy for this implication be divided into the following steps:

1. Let $K = J_m(\lambda)$. Show that $v$ is a cyclic vector of $K$ iff its final component is non-zero.
2. Show that if $p(\lambda) \neq 0$, then $p(K) v$ is also a cyclic vector of $K$.
3. Let $p_1(x) = (x - \lambda_2)^{m_2} \cdots (x - \lambda_k)^{m_k}$. Show that if $v$ satisfies the hypotheses of the statement, then $p_1(J)v$ has the form $(w, 0)$, where $w$ is a cyclic vector of $J_{m_1}(\lambda_1)$.
4. Argue inductively: with the hypothesis that the vector $(v_{m_1 + 1}, \dots v_{d})$ is a cyclic vector of $J_{m_2}(\lambda_2) \oplus \cdots \oplus J_{m_k}(\lambda_k)$, deduce that $v$ is a cyclic vector of $J$.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer! Relating to the claim, point 1: I'm not sure I understand the statement "the $j$th component of $v$ is non-zero for each $k$ of the form $j = \sum_{p=1}^q m_p$ for $p=1,\ldots,k$. What is $q$?

Comment: That was supposed to say for $q = 1,\dots,k$

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!