# Finding the generator for a cyclic module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, and $T:V \to V$ a linear transformation. We all know that $V$ can be considered an $F[x]$-module. Moreoever, we know that if the minimal polynomial is equal to the characteristic polynomial, then $V$ is actually a cyclic $F[x]$-module. This follows immediately from invariant decomposition.

My question is, do we have an explicit way to find the generator $v \in V$?

From the above blurb, we know that $V \cong F[x]/(m_T(x))$ where $m_T(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$. So, in order to find $v$, we just need to find the element in $V$ that maps to $\bar{1} \in F[x]/(m_T(x))$ under that isomorphism. But what is our isomorphism?

Comment: For what it's worth, a "randomly chosen" vector $v$ will be a cyclic vector.

Comment: @BenGrossmann So any vector will generate $V$ as an $F[x]$-module?

Comment: No, but "almost all vectors" will generate $V$ as an $F[x]$ module

Comment: In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3723338/81360), I give a complete characterization of the cyclic vectors (i.e. minimal generators of the module) in terms of the Jordan normal form.

Comment: Another way of putting it is that the set of vectors that **fail** to generate the module form a union of finitely many proper subspaces of $V$. If $V$ is identified with $\Bbb Q^n, \Bbb R^n,$ or $\Bbb C^n$, then this set of "bad" vectors has [Lebesgue measure zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure).

Comment: @BenGrossmann I will read that post. Thanks!